# dualhead with tmux and two xterm windows

Tags: tmux, multi-monitor, xterm

I'm running a dualhead system. Unfortunately, my monitors do not sport the same resolution, so I can't "just" use a huge xterm window spanning both screens. Also I imagine that it would be hard to keep a split at the right position.

What I would like to do is run two fullscreen xterms, one per screen, have them run tmux attached to the same session, but displaying different windows/split panes. It should be possible to seamlessly switch between split panes on one screen to those on the other, so that everything "feels" like one big window.

Any ideas on how to set this up?